# How do I know what arguments were used to mount

Tags: linux, mount

I have a linux system with something mounted to /dev/sdb1. How do I know what command was used to mount it?

Comment: Do you want to know what caused it to be mounted, or what options it was mounted with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mount` command by itself will tell you the options which were used to mount all mounted filesystems.  For example:

```
# mount
/dev/mapper/vg00-rootlv on / type ext3 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
none on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
none on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
none on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /var/run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
none on /var/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /lib/init/rw type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
none on /var/lib/ureadahead/debugfs type debugfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/mapper/vg00-applv on /app type ext3 (rw)
/dev/mapper/vg00-homelv on /home type ext3 (rw)
```